# Pandas: Divide column data by number if row of next column contains certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consists of three columns

```
qty     unit_of_measure     qty_cal
3          nodes               nan
4          nodes               nan  
5          nodes               nan
6          cores               nan
7          nodes               nan
10         cores               nan  
3          nodes               nan
```

I would like to add a condition to populate **qty_cal**.

The condition is if unit_of_measure is equal to "nodes" populate the row value of qty into qty_cal

If it's "cores" divide qty value by 16 and populate qty_cal

The code I have tried is,

```
if ppn_df['unit_of_measure'] == 'Nodes': 
    ppn_df['qty'] 

elif ppn_df['unit_of_measure'] =='Cores':
    ppn_df['qty'] / 16
```

I'm getting an error of

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I'm not sure why I'm getting this value error. I don't understand why the if statement is ambiguous.

Can anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
df['qty_cal'] = np.where(df['unit_of_measure'] == 'nodes', df['qty'], df['qty']/16)
```

Comment: I've never used np.where that works a trick and looks very easy to read. Thanks for your help!! Worked a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The statement `ppn_df['unit_of_measure']` returns a series (a column) with all the values in it, not a single item.  One way to do this is with an `apply` or a `map`

Try this

```
ppn_df.qty_cal = ppn_df.apply(lambda x: x['qty'] if x['unit_of_measure'] == 'nodes' else x['qty'] / 16, axis=1)
```

This function will execute the `lambda` function for each row in the series

Comment: can you please have a look into my question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083576/pandas-row-filters-and-and-division-from-specific-rows-and-columns]